# Yandex Map Kit + маркеры

Tags: yandexmapkit, android

Использую в Android-проекте Yandex Map Kit. Добавляю маркеры на карту с помощью DragAndDropItem. Однако, остается непонятными два вопроса:

1. Как можно отследить окончание перетаскивания маркера?
2. Как отследить клик по маркеру?

Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Расширь класс **DragAndDropOverlay**

```
    import ru.yandex.yandexmapkit.overlay.drag.DragAndDropItem;

    public interface DragAndDropItemListener {
        public void OnEndDrag(DragAndDropItem item);
        public void OnSingleTap(DragAndDropItem item);
    }

    import ru.yandex.yandexmapkit.MapController;
    import ru.yandex.yandexmapkit.overlay.OverlayItem;
    import ru.yandex.yandexmapkit.overlay.drag.DragAndDropItem;
    import ru.yandex.yandexmapkit.overlay.drag.DragAndDropOverlay;

    public class MyDragAndDropOverlay extends DragAndDropOverlay{

    DragAndDropItemListener mDragAndDropItemListener;
    DragAndDropItem mDraggingDragAndDropItem = null;
        boolean isDragging = false;

    public MyDragAndDropOverlay(MapController arg0) {
        super(arg0);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

        @Override
        public boolean onLongPress(float arg0, float arg1) {
            DragAndDropItem item = (DragAndDropItem) this.a(arg0, arg1);
            if(item!=null){
                mDraggingDragAndDropItem = item;
                isDragging = true;
            }
            return super.onLongPress(arg0, arg1);
        }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(float arg0, float arg1) {
        OverlayItem item = a(arg0, arg1);
        if(item != null){
            if(mDragAndDropItemListener!=null){
                mDragAndDropItemListener.OnSingleTap((DragAndDropItem) item);
            }
        }
        return super.onSingleTapUp(arg0, arg1);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onUp(float arg0, float arg1) {
        if(mDraggingDragAndDropItem!=null && isDragging){
                if(mDragAndDropItemListener!=null){
                mDragAndDropItemListener.OnEndDrag((DragAndDropItem) item);
            }
                mDraggingDragAndDropItem = null;
                isDragging = false;

            }
        }

        return super.onUp(arg0, arg1);
    }

    public void setDragAndDropItemListener(DragAndDropItemListener listener){
        mDragAndDropItemListener = listener;
    }

}
    MyDragAndDropOverlay overlay = new MyDragAndDropOverlay(mMapController);

    overlay.setDragAndDropItemListener(new DragAndDropItemListener(){

            @Override
            public void OnEndDrag(DragAndDropItem item) {
                Toast.makeText(Main.this, "бросили", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void OnSingleTap(DragAndDropItem item) {
                Toast.makeText(Main.this, "кликнули", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

    });
```

Comment: Так вот для чего нужен загадочный метод a() :) Спасибо! Все работает, только в onUp() item всегда равно null.

Comment: если бы был не выводилось бы "бросили", а у меня выводится

Comment: Перепроверил несколько раз, всегда один и тот же результат - null. Может быть у вас используется более ранняя версия библиотеки, где это иначе себя ведет... Либо у меня какие-то настройки карты отличаются, что дает такой вот эффект (хотя я попробовал поотключать к дефолту, но эффекта нет). Затрудняюсь что-то еще предположить. Тем не менее, все равно, большое спасибо!

Comment: возможно, я проверял не на только что загруженной с гитхаб библиотеки, как появится возможность, загружу и отпишусь

Comment: Буду признателен. Пока что сделал крайне неоптимально... Внешне незаметно, отрабатывает моментально, но не комильфо.

Comment: у меня старая библиотека была, поправил код в ответе, проверил, работает с новой

Comment: Да, теперь все отлично работает. Спасибо!